# How to add a right-click context menu to your controls in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, contextmenu, firemonkey, popupmenu

I've made a `Form` with an `Image` using the [DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python), but what I want now is a right-click context menu on the image. When I right-click on the image, then it should bring up a context popup menu as you see here in VSCode when I right-click:

[image: Visual Studio Code Editor Context Menu Right Click]

I have the following code that makes my `Form` and `Image`:

```
import os
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form with Image and Context Menu'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 1000

        self.imgDirt = Image(self)
        self.imgDirt.Parent = self
        self.imgDirt.Align = "Client"
        self.imgDirt.Margins.Top = 40
        self.imgDirt.Margins.Left = 40
        self.imgDirt.Margins.Right = 40
        self.imgDirt.Margins.Bottom = 40

        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.imgDirt.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path + '\dirt.png')


def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

I tried doing things like this, but it doesn't work (`NameError: name 'ContextMenu' is not defined`):

```
self.cm = ContextMenu(self)
self.cm.Items.Add("Item 1")
self.cm.Items.Add("Item 2")
self.cm.Items.Add("Item 3")
```

Same for:

```
self.cm = PopUpMenu(self)
```

How do I do this in FMX for Python? Simple Right-click Context Menu PopUp on the Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own problem. It is a `PopupMenu` and not a `PopUpMenu`. So the wording is case-sensitive.

To create a PopupMenu (Context Menu), here's the code:

```
# Step 1: Create a PopupMenu
self.cm = PopupMenu(self)
self.cm.Parent = self



# Step 2: Create MenuItems
self.MenuItem1 = MenuItem(self)
self.MenuItem1.Parent = self.cm
self.MenuItem1.Text = "Item 1"

self.MenuItem2 = MenuItem(self)
self.MenuItem2.Parent = self.cm
self.MenuItem2.Text = "Item 2"

self.MenuItem3 = MenuItem(self)
self.MenuItem3.Parent = self.cm
self.MenuItem3.Text = "Item 3"



# Step 3: Assign PopupMenu to Image
self.imgDirt.PopupMenu = self.cm
```

It's basically split into three parts.

1. Create the `PopupMenu` component.
2. Create the `MenuItem` components, give them a Caption (`Text`), and set their `Parent` to the `PopupMenu` component.
3. Assign the `PopupMenu` to whatever component you want it to appear on. I assigned it to my `Image` component.

This is how it will look when I right-click on the image:
[image: Python GUI App with Context Menu (Popup Menu)]